# What is the definition of a half space in a riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I have stumbled upon the definition of **halfspace in model geometry** i.e $S^n$ with the standard intrinsic metric, $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard metric and the Hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ with the canonical metric.

I assume by that (up to isometry) the following things were meant: 
The upper hemisphere in $\mathbb{S}^n$, the upper half plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the right quadrant in the upper half-plane model of $\mathbb{H}^n$.

I have not been able to find a definition for half space of a Riemannian manifold written down anywhere. Do you know of any reference?

Comment: Can you give the reference where you see "halfspace in model geometry"?

Comment: Semiconcave functions in Alexandrov’s geometry by Anton Petrunin on page 4 here is an arxiv link https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0292.pdf

Comment: There's not really any sensible definition of half-space for general Riemannian manifolds. What makes the definition work in $\mathbb{S}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathbb{H}^n$ is that each has many totally geodesic $n-1$ dimensional sub manifolds

Answer (score 0):

On a complete Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$, if you take two arbitrary distinct points $p_1$ and $p_2$, the sets $$H_1 = \{p\in\mathcal{M}|d_{\mathcal{M}}(p,p_1)<d_{\mathcal{M}}(p,p_2)\}$$ $$H_2 = \{p\in\mathcal{M}|d_{\mathcal{M}}(p,p_1)>d_{\mathcal{M}}(p,p_2)\}$$ give two complementary open half-spaces. Conversely, any pair of complementary open half-spaces in $\mathcal{M}$ can be thus described.

Even I'm looking for a somewhat more 'working' definition, but this is possibly fine for most things.